# Install 4.3 (OTA) on rooted Nexus 4 (CWM + stock rom, kernel)

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, nexus-4, ota-update, 4.3-jelly-bean

I'm running Android 4.2.2 on my Nexus 4. It is rooted, and I have ClockworkMod recovery installed, but rom and kernel are stock. I received the OTA update to 4.3, and would like to install it, but it failed. (With a message that CWM couldn't verify a signature. I remember that the previous OTA worked, and I think I had to re-root, but that was easy.)

How can I get the stock 4.3 update on my phone, while keeping root and CWM, and especially keeping all my data? Step-by-step instructions would be great.

Also, I'm curious, what is the technical reason that the update doesn't install?

---

Update: I found some [instructions here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/494785/20130726/nexus4-android43-jwr66v-jellybean-official-ota-update.htm), however they didn't work for me. I get the following error from CWM while applying update.zip:

```
Installing: /sdcard/0/update.zip
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Installing update...

Warning no file_contextsVerifying current system...

assert failed: apply_patch_check("/system/bin/app_process", "76c3a9a7a6d400a9ff3e4db391327daa33aa0663", "2a221441bf06f2618aa6c35ae0cade13bd4f6e1b")
E:Error in /sdcard/0/update.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

Update 2:
I forgot that I tried out Xposed some time ago. Apparently this modified /system/bin/app_process. I removed it by starting *Xposed Installer*, and then selecting "Uninstall (restore app_process)" and (probably not neccessary), "Clean up (complete removal of the framework)". I did one complete reboot, and then rebooted into recovery mode to continue the update. But now it hangs because "build.prop" is modified (don't remember changing that). I wonder if there is a way to just flash the new OS files (not patches), overwriting any modifications, but keeping all settings and user files...

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like the "/system/bin/app_process" has been modified and so it doesn't match the signature required. There are 2 ways to fix this, either get a copy of the stock file from another phone/rom or flash the factory image for 4.3

Edit: After reading "update 2" it sounds like you want the factory image option detailed below.

AndroidPolice has a step by step guide [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/24/how-to-flash-your-nexus-4-to-android-4-3-jwr66v-and-root-it-right-now/). I've duplicated the steps in case that page dies:

> Download the full [occam factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occamjwr66v), which includes the full system, bootloader, recovery, kernel (boot.img), and radio. It's a clean slate for these components - they'll flash cleanly over anything you have now.
>
> Instead of using the bundled script called flash-all, you will unpack the tgz (tar/gz) archive, and then the zip contained within as well. This will put all the components into one folder:
>
> Follow the excellent guide over here and make sure to omit step D10, which overwrites userdata. Here are the commands you will be executing, for reference:
>
> 1. adb reboot bootloader
> 2. fastboot flash bootloader bootloader*.img
> 3. fastboot reboot-bootloader
> 4. fastboot flash radio radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1700.84.img
> 5. fastboot reboot-bootloader
> 6. fastboot flash system system.img
> 7. fastboot flash boot boot.img
> 8. fastboot format cache
> 9. fastboot reboot
>
> Note: Instead of unpacking the image*.zip and flashing system and boot
> manually, you can actually do fastboot update image*.zip - this won't
> delete data (you would pass a -w flag if you wanted that to happen),
> but it will re-flash recovery back to stock if you were running a
> custom one. You can then flash it back, or just use the commands above
> instead. Either way, the result will be the same.

You will then need to re-root (there is no way to go from 4.2.2 to 4.3 keeping root at the moment) by following the steps in this [thread](https://plus.google.com/+Chainfire/posts/Jkuu84odnx6) (I won't link to the file itself as it is being updated as/when issues are found.).

Comment: I don't see any boot.img file for the 4.3 update for the Nexus 4 that I downloaded. I have the bootloader.img, image.zip, and radio.img. Where's the boot.img?

Comment: You need to unzip the image.zip as well. the boot.img and system.img are in there.

Comment: Gave up on trying to flash these manually after first boot was getting stuck. I extracted the factory image to my ADB directory and ran "flash-all.bat" and it booted right up first time after that. The flash-all.bat does a bit more than the above procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.  I ended up downloading the stock 4.2.2, flashing that (also un-rooting my phone), then installing the OTA update.

Comment: Do you know where one can download the stock OS (Assuming there is a legal download)? Also, does flashing preserve your data?

Comment: @jdm Oficial stock roms from Google: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occamjwr66v

Comment: I don't think your data will be preserved. And yes grab the images from the official Google page.  It looks like 4.3 is there now.  Also, here is a link to a guide to flashing 4.3: http://bit.ly/16aTnvY     That guide states that you won't lose data.

Comment: OTA is able to preserve your user data. I don't believe that flashing the factory image is able to preserve all your user data.