# Nexus 4 bricked by OTA upgrade

Tags: nexus-4, unbricking, 4.3-jelly-bean

In early august, both my nexus 4 and my nexus 7 got the OTA upgrade. The nexus 7 one worked without any problems. The one for my phone actually bricked my phone.

First it was stuck on the X-logo screen. I reflashed 4.2.2 and suddenly the phone had problems it never had before: random shutdowns, sudden locking of the SIM card, not booting unless plugged in.

I also did all the wipes and factory resets Play support told me to do, and a factory reset and everything. I even replaced my SIM card and flashed 4.2.0 and it still has the same problems.

I found a way to get 4.3 to get beyond the X screen, by flashing the radio back to an older version, but the above problems persist.

Is there anything that isn't overwritten when you reflash an older version? (I'm thinking drivers or something like that) If so, what could it be? And how can I get them back to an older version?

Since I voided my warranty (screen was broken and repaired by third party), I'm wondering if I can hold Google (or at least Android) responsible for breaking my phone...

TIA

Comment: Apparently, I'm not alone either: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/gsBvuZzG_xc%5B1-25-false%5D

Answer (score 1):

If you've wiped everything you have probably wiped the system partition meaning there is nothing to boot up to. Try following the steps [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50035/30530) to install a factory image which will wipe your device and completely re-install everything.

If this doesn't work then it is likely that there is a hardware issue, which due to you having the screen replaced is unlikely to be covered under warranty (nor will Google/LG take responsibility for it)

Comment: I have installed so many factory images in the last week, that i can do it blindly :)

The problem is that even with older factory images flashed, my phone has problems that I didn't have before the 4.3 update.