# install KitKat factory image on nexus-4

Tags: nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat

I have never flashed rom or anything close to it on my mobile so far. I have a nexus-4 and would like to install 4.4 KitKat from the factory image published by Google. Is there any site that provides detailed steps on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50035/30530) but get the 4.4 rather than the 4.3 factory image.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions posted at technostall and that worked for me.

Link: 
http://www.technostall.com/nexus-4-android-44-kitkat-unlock-bootloader/

Comment: When that link no longer functions this answer has no value.