# Nexus 5 gives Status 7 error when flashing 5.1 OTA

Tags: adb, nexus-5, stock-android, fastboot, ota-update

I've been trying all day to install 5.1 OTA via ADB. In my struggle, I tried installing TWRP to try to get it to work, but it didn't. I since flashed the stock recovery.

When trying to flash via ADB, this is my output log:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installing update...
Verifying current system...
"System/bin/install-recovery.sh" has unexpected contents.
E:Error in /sideload/package.zip
(Status 7)

Installation aborted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clue is in the output log:

> "System/bin/install-recovery.sh" has unexpected contents.

Since Android 5, OTA installs verify each partition as a whole so any changes will result in verification failing even if the file is not changed by the update. Something has changed the `install-recovery.sh` file, so you will need to revert the change or copy the original file back from a backup.

Comment: On my OP, someone said this was a possible duplicate of another question. Would flashing the system image from the 5.0.1 factory zip fix the recovery issue?

Comment: Yes, although you could just flash straight to the 5.1 factory image.

Comment: That erases everything, doesn't it?

Comment: It _can_ but doesn't have to. If you follow (and adjust the  names for the relevant 5.1 file) the steps [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50025/install-4-3-ota-on-rooted-nexus-4-cwm-stock-rom-kernel/50035#50035) you can flash without wiping (assuming you have a unlocked bootloader).