# nexus 5 android 5.1 installing

Tags: ota-update, 5.1-lollipop

I am trying to upgrade my Nexus 6 with version 5.0.1 (Build number LRX22C) via OTA to Android 5.1.

The OTA update is downloaded successfully and after pressing "Restart & Install" I see a dead droid with the message "Error!".

The phone was rooted and I unrooted it via SuperSU. Did not help. Wiping cache partition also did not change anything.

Comment: You've specified N5 in your title and N6 in your question. You should probably clarify this. Your [other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/104765/981) also references the N5, so it's not clear if you were trying to post two different questions or the same one got posted twice. If you *were* trying to post two different ones, then the fact that you are seeing the same exact behavior on two different devices would seem to suggest that this issue is not device specific, so combining them might be the best choice anyway.

Comment: It probably is about the Nexus 5, taking like a majority vote : Nexus 5 : 2 Titles, 1 Question; Nexus 6 : 1 Question. So, @shamim AKHTAR , please specify which Nexus model you have, the 'shamu' Nexus 6 or the 'hammerhead' Nexus 5.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 5, OTA installs verify each partition as a whole so any changes will result in verification failing even if the file is not changed by the update. You said that you unrooted via SuperSU but it is likely that there is something that has changed in the `system` partition. Usually the error message will indicate the file that has caused it to fail.

Therefore, your options are to restore the `system` partition to the 'stock' state (removing any files you've added, reverting any changes to files and re-instating any deleted files) and flash the OTA or flash a factory image using the steps in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50035/30530) (using the 5.1 file names in place of the 4.3 ones in that answer)