# Can I update my Rooted Nexus 5 4.2 to 5.1 without bricking it?

Tags: nexus-5

I'm scared of updating my nexus 5 4.2 system as i've read reports of people's rooted system going into a boot loop when doing an update. Is there a safe way of upgrading when my system is rooted?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/104846/30530

Comment: There are often well documented ways to recover from a bootloop. Just make a backup and flash away!