# My Nexus 5 won't update

Tags: nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop, operating-system

So my phone was doing random shutdowns. I thought maybe rooting it would solve the problem. And it did.. but now I can't do any updates.

There is this 10.1 MB Update that keeps prompting to install ever since March 2015. I have tried unrooting it back but still no luck.

The major problem is I want to download the new Marshmallow software update but well I can't. My nexus 5 always says it's up-to-date. I decided to manually download and install it. So I restarted phone and went to recovery mode for TWRP and I initiated the install. And I got this error `error executing updater binary in zip` etc.

How can I get Marshmallow on my Nexus 5?

[image]
[image]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

*Sorry for the bad res image, had to use my laptop for that.*

P.S: I have Lollipop 5.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can read on the image you posted it looks like your device has 4.4.4 not 5.1.1, and possibly a custom rom rather than the stock one (it looks like `omni_hammerhead/hammerhead: 4.4.4` in the screenshot).

If you have a custom ROM you will not be able to apply an OTA update as they will only work for the stock ROM.

Your best bet might be to flash a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerhead) (see my instructions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50025/install-4-3-ota-on-rooted-nexus-4-cwm-stock-rom-kernel/50035#50035) - you'll need to modify the file names but the process should be the same). You should note that unless you've already unlocked your bootloader this **will** wipe your device, and even if you have if you don't follow the steps correctly it still might (so you'll have to set everything up from scratch again unless you have a backup).

Comment: I don't mind it wiping everything - I did a factory reset yesterday (which I thought might help me but did not).

Comment: I will try what you posted and get back to you!

Comment: Ah, sorry. You need the `fastboot.exe` (and possibly `adb.exe`) files. I've uploaded them to my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BybuxSlB3AbNRjlweU9xdjVFbTQ/view?usp=sharing)  or you can download the full SDK from [Google](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools). Put the files I uploaded in the same directory as the extracted .img files and you can then run the flash-all.bat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30049/discussion-between-bmdixon-and-samer-el-sabeh).